# Why I am getting "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" in my DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I believe I have bound my data correctly, but I can't seem to get my text property for each SelectListItem to show properly.

My model:

```
public class Licenses
    {
        public SelectList LicenseNames { get; set; }
        public string SelectedLicenseName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult License()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable LicsTable = BW.SQLServer.Table("GetLicenses", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProfressionalActivitiesConnection"].ToString());
            ProfessionalActivities.Models.Licenses model = new ProfessionalActivities.Models.Licenses();
            model.LicenseNames = new SelectList(LicsTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = row["Description"].ToString(),
                Text = "test"
            }));
            return PartialView("_AddLicense", model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var t = ex;
            return PartialView("_AddLicense");
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("LicenseNames", new SelectList(Model.LicenseNames, "Value", "Text", Model.LicenseNames.SelectedValue), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control focusMe" } })
```

Comment: In addition to Shyju's answer, note that the 2nd parameter of `DropDownList()` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. You create that using `new SelectListItem { Value = row["Description"].ToString(), Text = "test"})` which is all you need. Creating a 2nd identical one in the controller using `new SelectList()` (where you forgot to set the `Text` and `Value` properties) and then creating a 3rd identical one in the view is just pointless extra overhead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `Items` property of your `LicenseNames` property which is of type `SelectList`

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedLicenseName", new SelectList(Model.LicenseNames.Items,
                                       "Value", "Text", Model.LicenseNames.SelectedValue))
```

Or with  the `DropDownListFor` helper method

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(d=>d.SelectedLicenseName, 
                                         Model.LicenseNames.Items as List<SelectListItem>)
```

So when you post your form, you can inspect the `SelectedLicenseName` property

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Licenses model)
{
  //check model.SelectedLicenseName
}
```

Comment: Ok that works. Now how do I get the selected value from the SelectList to be assigned to my SelectedLicenseName property when i POST?

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to use the form element name as "SelectedLicenseName" and read that when the form is posted.

Comment: so using your second option - the one with DropDownListForm, i get this error when i try to call the partial view initially.

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedLicenseName'.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `DropDownListFor` because it will use your model property(LicenseNames) to render the dropdown items. This code works fine for me.

Comment: i have this: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLicenseName, Model.LicenseNames.Items as List<SelectListItem>, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control focusMe" } })

Comment: In your action method, when an exception occur(in your catch block, you are still returning the same partial view,but not passing a valid object of your Licenses view model. I guess that is what is happening. Your razor code is expecting a view model passed to it, but you are not doing it. You need to fix it.

Comment: i dont think that's the case. when i debug in my action method, it isn't throwing the error there. its returning just fine using the line that includes the model getting passed into PartialView().  I get the error popping up in VS on the html helper in the view itself.

Comment: I tried this code and it worked fine for me. What is your partial view typed to ? `License` ?

Comment: Yes. Well, Licenses, but yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105188/discussion-between-bubbas-and-shyju).

Comment: this is not working     ViewData["ProductTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductType, "ProductName", "ProductDescription");
           return  (from pt in _context.ProductType
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Value = pt .ProductName,
                               Text = pt .ProductDescription
                           });

Comment: @BlueLamp82 Post a new question with relevant code and specific error you are getting if any

Comment: question is here now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518407/mvc-core-selectlist-dropdown-in-controller-error-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rende

Comment: @BlueLamp82 I posted a response to your question

Comment: All it took was adding ".items"...You are amazing. Thank you for helping after I spent 4 hours on this..

Answer (score 2):

I explicitly set the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` names.

```
new SelectListItem
{
    Value = row["Description"].ToString(),
    Text = "test"
}), "Value", "Text");
```

Then there's no need to write `Model.LicenseNames.Items as List<SelectListItem>` in your views (as suggested in your accepted answer).