# MVC Core SelectList Dropdown in Controller Error "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a SelectList Dropdown in MVC.

I prefer select list to be in repository, not in controller.
How do I call a repository, without even referring to the name of the fields in the Model. Only thing I want to refer to is repository.

I am receiving error with this "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem"
This resource does not help yet: 
[Why I am getting "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" in my DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755862/why-i-am-getting-system-web-mvc-selectlistitem-in-my-dropdownlist/35755992?noredirect=1#comment87970734_35755992)

I am reading many examples on internet, This is the original code,

**Original Code:**

```
ViewData["ProductTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductType, "ProductName", "ProductDescription");
```

**I am trying to get the code to work like this:**

Receive error: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem"

```
 ViewData["ProductTypeId"] = new SelectList(_producttyperepository.GetAllLookupKey());

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllLookupKey()
    {

       return  (from ptin _context.ProductType pt
                       select new SelectListItem
                       {
                           Value = pt.ProductTypeName,
                           Text = pt.ProductDescription
                       });

    }

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ProductType" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ProductType" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductTypeId"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ProductType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Uhm, try just `ViewData["ProductTypeId"] = _producttyperepository.GetAllLookupKey();`

Comment: Naming is confusing. POCO entity is named as `ProductType`. Does view model have property name `ProductType`?

Comment: tried that already "An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately."   It was working originally with Viewbag, for some reason, will relook

Comment: yes, Win correct, viewmodel is also product type, I will rename this, started programming 3 month ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `GetAllLookupKey` would not compile! Use this version.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllLookupKey()
{
    return _context.ProductType.Select( pt=>new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = pt.ProductTypeName,
        Text = pt.ProductDescription
    }).ToList();
}
```

Also, there is no need to create a second `SelectList`. Your `GetAllLookupKey` method returns a collection of `SelectListItem` and you can set that to your ViewData.

```
 ViewData["ProductTypeId"] = _producttyperepository.GetAllLookupKey();
```

The `SelectListItem` class is defined in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;` So make sure you have a using statement which includes that namespace in your class.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
```

If this is in a different project than the one which has the Controllers. make sure your project has a reference to the assembly which has this namespace & class.

While that might fix our problem, `SelectListItem` is a class to represent more of a UI layer concern. ***IMHO***, You should not have your repository return that. Have your repository return  more generic data (Ex : List of ProductType) and have your UI layer code (controller action/UI service layer etc) generate the list of SelectListItem objects from this ProductType list.